# How do I run a logit/probit model only with an intercept in R aod?

Tags: r

I am doing this for econometrics purposes and want to test the significance of all coefficients, it just would be better for my calculations. I have tried regressing the variable on itself and it returned some result with only an intercept, but i am not sure if this is correct.

```
myprobit0 <- glm(target ~ target, 
                data = data_numeric, family = binomial(link = "probit") )
```

Could you please suggest a proper way to only estimate the model with a constant?

Comment: I think `glm(target ~ 1, ...)` should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

vecs = rep(1 ,length(target)) // give length of your data as second argument

myprobit0 <- glm(target ~ vecs ,
data = data_numeric, family = binomial(link = "probit") )

Comment: No need for a vector of 1s. MrFlick’s suggestion will work. And makes the use of the intercept-only model explicit.